# How to select a specific tag within this html?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

How would I select all of the titles in this page

```
http://bulletin.columbia.edu/columbia-college/departments-instruction/african-american-studies/#coursestext
```

for example: I'm trying to get all the lines similar to this:

```
AFAS C1001 Introduction to African-American Studies. 3 points.
```

main_page is iterating through all of the school classes from here so I can grab all of the titles like above:

```
http://bulletin.columbia.edu/columbia-college/departments-instruction/  

for page in main_page:
    sub_abbrev = page.find("div", {"class": "courseblock"})
```

I have this code but I can't figure out exactly how to select all of the ('strong') tags of the first child. 
Using latest python and beautiful soup 4 to web-scrape.
Lmk if there is anything else that is needed.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over elements with `courseblock` class, then, for every course, get the element with `courseblocktitle` class. Working example using [`select()` and `select_one()` methods](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://bulletin.columbia.edu/columbia-college/departments-instruction/african-american-studies/#coursestext"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

for course in soup.select(".courseblock"):
    title = course.select_one("p.courseblocktitle").get_text(strip=True)
    print(title)
```

Prints:

```
AFAS C1001 Introduction to African-American Studies.3 points.
AFAS W3030 African-American Music.3 points.
AFAS C3930 (Section 3) Topics in the Black Experience: Concepts of Race and Racism.4 points.
AFAS C3936 Black Intellectuals Seminar.4 points.
AFAS W4031 Protest Music and Popular Culture.3 points.
AFAS W4032 Image and Identity in Contemporary Advertising.4 points.
AFAS W4035 Criminal Justice and the Carceral State in the 20th Century United States.4 points.
AFAS W4037 (Section 1) Third World Studies.4 points.
AFAS W4039 Afro-Latin America.4 points.
```

---

A good follow-up question from @double_j:

> In the OPs example, he has a space between the points. How would you keep that? That's how the data shows on the site, even thought it's not really in the source code.

I though about using `separator` argument of the [`get_text()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text), but that would also add an extra space before the last dot. Instead, I would join the `strong` element texts via `str.join()`:

```
for course in soup.select(".courseblock"):
    title = " ".join(strong.get_text() for strong in course.select("p.courseblocktitle > strong"))
    print(title)
```

Comment: In the OPs example, he has a space between the points. How would you keep that? That's how the data shows on the site, even thought it's not really in the source code.